# Problem with jQuery index()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, indexing

There must be something simple I am missing.  I'm trying to get the index of the element but keep getting -1.

HTML:

```
<div id="rating_boxes">
<img src="/img/ratingbox.gif" class="ratingbox" alt="Rate this Speech" />
<img src="/img/ratingbox.gif" class="ratingbox" alt="Rate this Speech" />
<img src="/img/ratingbox.gif" class="ratingbox" alt="Rate this Speech" />
<img src="/img/ratingbox.gif" class="ratingbox" alt="Rate this Speech" />
<img src="/img/ratingbox.gif" class="ratingbox" alt="Rate this Speech" />
<img src="/img/ratingbox.gif" class="ratingbox" alt="Rate this Speech" />
<img src="/img/ratingbox.gif" class="ratingbox" alt="Rate this Speech" />
<img src="/img/ratingbox.gif" class="ratingbox" alt="Rate this Speech" />
<img src="/img/ratingbox.gif" class="ratingbox" alt="Rate this Speech" />
<img src="/img/ratingbox.gif" class="ratingbox" alt="Rate this Speech" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("img.ratingbox").hover(function() {
    var index = $(this).parent().index(this);
            // have also tried $("#rating_boxes").index(this);
            // and $("#rating_boxes").index($(this));
            // and $(this).parent().index($(this));
    alert(index);
    $(this).attr('src', '/img/ratingbox-selected.gif');
}, function() {
    $(this).attr('src', '/img/ratingbox.gif');
});
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I tend to steer clear of using `index()` in jQuery 1.3.2 and previous as it feels unintuitive to use. I simply use

```
$(this).prevAll().length
```

to get the index. calling `size()` on `prevAll()` simply returns the value of the `length` property, so I prefer to just use length directly and skip the extra function call.

For example,

```
$("img.ratingbox").hover(function() {
    var index = $(this).prevAll().length;
    alert(index);
    $(this).attr('src', '/img/ratingbox-selected.gif');
}, function() {
    $(this).attr('src', '/img/ratingbox.gif');
});
```

In jQuery 1.4, you'll simply be able to call `index()` on a jQuery object to get the index of the first element in the object.

Comment: I would upvote this 20 times if I could. .index() does not make sense.

Answer (score 12):

`index()` returns the index of the given element with a list of elements, not within a parent element.  To find the index of the clicked image, you need to find all the images, not the *parent* of all the images.

You want something like this:

```
// Find all the images in our parent, and then find our index with that set of images
var index = $(this).parent().find("img").index(this);
```

You're also using the id selector instead of the class selector in your 2nd example. Instead of

```
$("#rating_boxes").index($(this)); // your way - select by ID
```

You want

```
$(".rating_boxes").index(this); // select by class
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know the position of the rating box, a more robust way is to use:

```
var index = $(this).prevAll('img').size();
```

I.e., calculate the number of img elements before this element. The index method requires you to first select the parent element, then all img elements inside. This is a tad faster.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a div or section which also contains img before this div, the solution

> var index = $(this).prevAll().length;

will not work as it gives same answer as using

> $(this).index();

The solution that works fine for any of these scenario is

> var index = $(this).parent().find("img").index(this);

I have just applied these two methods to solve my problem.